# Building a database

Tags: java, html, database, netbeans, glassfish

I am attempting to build a database that will allow a user to upload their music to be accessed by someone else/third party. How would I create it so that the music can be uploaded to a database but providing a path for it to be accessed from where it is stored?

As in A Band upload “Song” and it is then streamed by A Fan.

If it can't upload to a database I need to upload it to a server.

We are building the back end in Java and the front end in HTML.

We are also using Glassfish and Netbeans for writing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store files in a BLOB field in a database for example. Another possibility would be to store them directly on the file system, but it has its problems (such as the lack of metadata).

Then you'll need to figure how you want to map each file, for example `http://myserver.com/Artist/Album/Songname` or `http://myserver.com/listen?uniqueid=743`.

File upload servlets are available all over the web, so that shouldn't be a problem. The rest is up to your programming skills (this might be too big of a project for you).

Then you'll just need to connect those things together, and that's the part where you start to program (or hit the Google hard).